# Cost function in classification gives NaN as a result

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, nan

I am quite new to both python and machine learning and I am trying to create an ANN for a binary classification model in order to determine whether something is faulty or not. When I run the code down below, the cost function seem to come up as nan. Unfortunately, in order to come up with an accuracy percentage, I need the cost to be an actual number. Is there an obvious error in my code or is there another way to circumvent this problem by writing it differently? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
import csv  
import tensorflow as tf  
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import urllib.request as request  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

train_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/train_data.csv", sep=',', header = None)  
test_data = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/test_data.csv", sep=',', header = None)  

X_train = np.asarray(train_data)  
X_test = np.asarray(test_data)  

train_label = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/train_label.csv", sep=',', header = None)  
test_label = pd.read_csv("C:/Python35/test_label.csv", sep=',', header = None)  

y_train = np.asarray(train_label)  
y_test = np.asarray(test_label)  

labels_train = (np.arange(2) == y_train[:,None]).astype(np.float32)  
labels_test = (np.arange(2) == y_test[:,None]).astype(np.float32)  

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, X_train.shape[1]), name='inputs')  
label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2), name='labels')  

hid1_size = 128  
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hid1_size, X_train.shape[1]], stddev=0.01), name='w1')  
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=(hid1_size, 1)), name='b1')  
y1 = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(w1, tf.transpose(inputs)), b1)),  keep_prob=0.5)

hid2_size = 256  
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hid2_size, hid1_size], stddev=0.01), name='w2')  
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=(hid2_size, 1)), name='b2')  
y2 = tf.nn.dropout(tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(w2, y1), b2)), keep_prob=0.5)  

wo = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, hid2_size], stddev=0.01), name='wo')  
bo = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]), name='bo')  
yo = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(wo, y2), bo))  

lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(), name='learning_rate')  
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=yo, labels=label))  
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)  

pred = tf.nn.softmax(yo)  
pred_label = tf.argmax(pred, 1)  
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(label, 1))  
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))  

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  

config = tf.ConfigProto()  
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  

sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=config)  
sess.run(init)  

for learning_rate in [0.05, 0.01]:  
    for epoch in range(50):  
        avg_cost = 0.0  
        for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):  
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={lr:learning_rate,  
                                                          inputs: X_train[i, None],  
                                                          label: labels_train[i, None].reshape(-1,2)})  
            avg_cost += c  
        avg_cost /= X_train.shape[0]      
        if epoch % 10 == 0:  
            print("Epoch: {:3d}    Train Cost: {:.4f}".format(epoch, avg_cost))  

acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={inputs: X_train, label: labels_train.reshape(-1,2)})  
print("Train accuracy: {:3.2f}%".format(acc_train*100.0))  

acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={inputs: X_test, label: labels_test.reshape(-1,2)})  
print("Test accuracy:  {:3.2f}%".format(acc_test*100.0))
```

Comment: What learning rate are you using? A common cause for NaN costs is exploding gradients caused by an excessively large learning rate.

Comment: In the main training loop, I train for 50 epochs with a learning rate of 0.05 and another 50 epochs with a smaller learning rate of 0.01. When I try to print c, it prints several very large numbers, then some zeros, then some small number, and then finally it becomes nan.

Comment: I have managed to fix the nan result by following your advice by using a much smaller learning rate but is there a way to find the optimal rate rather than using trial and error and seeing what the end result is?

Comment: Unfortunately that's pretty much the only way. But you can try to use other optimizers like momentum optimizer and Adam optimizer (these and a bunch of others are already implemented in TensorFlow) which tend to be much more stable. You can also try using learning rate decay.